# login with fields and facebook using parse not giving desired result

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

previously i was using just the login fields and login but for the user to login. But now i need the "Login With Facebook" button. so i add these line of code

```
 facebookPermissions =    ["public_profile", "email"]

    fields = [PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword, .LogInButton, .SignUpButton, .PasswordForgotten, .Facebook]

    logInView?.facebookButton?.addTarget(self, action: "_loginWithFacebook", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

facebook login works but it is not giving desired results it is not saving email automatically as Parse have to handle itself.

previously i registered id using "mr.parv@gmail.com" and now i want to login with facebook then in this case it is creating new user with facebook token and not saving email.
[image]

```
- (void)_loginWithFacebook {
if (self.loading) {
    return;
}

self.loading = YES;
if ([_logInView.facebookButton isKindOfClass:[PFActionButton class]]) {
    [(PFActionButton *)_logInView.facebookButton setLoading:YES];
}

__weak typeof(self) wself = self;
PFUserResultBlock resultBlock = ^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    __strong typeof(wself) sself = wself;
    sself.loading = NO;
    if ([_logInView.facebookButton isKindOfClass:[PFActionButton class]]) {
        [(PFActionButton *)_logInView.facebookButton setLoading:NO];
    }

    if (user) {
        [sself _loginDidSucceedWithUser:user];
    } else if (error) {
        [sself _loginDidFailWithError:error];
    } else {
        // User cancelled login.
    }
};

Class fbUtils = NSClassFromString(@"PFFacebookUtils");
if ([fbUtils respondsToSelector:@selector(logInWithPermissions:block:)]) {
    // Facebook SDK v3 Login
    [fbUtils logInWithPermissions:_facebookPermissions block:resultBlock];
} else if ([fbUtils respondsToSelector:@selector(logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:block:)]) {
    // Facebook SDK v4 Login
    if ([self _permissionsContainsFacebookPublishPermission:_facebookPermissions]) {
        [fbUtils logInInBackgroundWithPublishPermissions:_facebookPermissions block:resultBlock];
    } else {
        [fbUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:_facebookPermissions block:resultBlock];
    }
} else {
    [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                format:@"Can't find PFFacebookUtils. Please link with ParseFacebookUtils or ParseFacebookUtilsV4 to enable login with Facebook."];
}
```

}

added the _loginWithFacebook method
[image: response of PFUser object]

Comment: can you show that method `_loginWithFacebook`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik -- i updated my questions with the "_loginWithFacebook" method and response screenshot.